# Spring, Maven: Correct the classpath of your application

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to create a maven version of the gradle-based treehouse 'unit-testing-a-spring-application' project used in this [course](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/unit-testing-a-spring-application). See course code [here](https://bitbucket.org/abitorgdout/spring-unit-testing-public/src/master/).

After not being able to build initially, I ended up adding dependency versions specified in the original gradle build file. Maven will build fine, but running the app gives this:

```
The following method did not exist:
    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)
Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource, is 
available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/C:/Users/home/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-
commons/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class

It was loaded from the following location:
    file:/C:/Users/home/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-
data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar

Action  
    Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of
 org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.
```

Several similar problems are solved here on S.O. by changing the version of some related dependency. I have tried various versions of the following to no avail (I stick normally with spring-boot-starter-parent v2.1.4 cause it works all the time with my projects):

```
spring-data-commons
spring-boot-starter-parent
```

I see the needed class below listed in my project Dependencies directory, but what dependency versions will work in this case? How can I solve this otherwise?

```
org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class
```

Comment: Please check your dependencies. Imo interface **RepositoryConfigurationSource** is in dependency A with version X and implementation of this interface is in dependency B with version Y. And interface in dependency B does not have this method. So probably interface was loaded from dependency A, but implementation is loaded from dependency B.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and found some mistakes. Since your project is a spring-boot one, you mustn't add direct spring dependencies in your pom file. Instead try to use spring-boot based dependencies. For instance, instead of having such this dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You must have the following one in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I made that change to my pom, rebuilt, reran, but got a different missing class: Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBea